# Unable to start program n Visual Studio 2022 & 2019

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I am unable to start the program in my local both in Visual Studio 2022 & 2019. I already clean and Build the solution. Can someone help me.

[image: Getting this error when trying to run]

> Unable to start program 'https://localhost:44355/'. The debugger is
> not properly installed. Cannot debug the requested type of code. Run
> setup to install or repair the debugger.

I tried to reinstall the visual studio. Restarted the system but still getting this error.

Answer (score 0):

This looks like an issue with the SDK not being installed correctly. It should of be installed as part of VS but it seems like it might of gotten removed. Try to download this https://dotnet.microsoft.com/en-us/download

It also could be an issue with your launchsettings.json or possibly program.cs/startup.cs but without a copy of that, it is hard to see what the issue is.